# Documents to register in Germany (Anmeldung)

Tags: germany, immigration, residency

Is it possible to download in advance the documents I will need to fill to register in Germany?

Since I do not speak German, I might need a bit of time to fill the documents as I will need to translate every word. Is there a website from where I can download them?

I tried looking on the website of the town I am going to register but it is all written in German only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To register you need your passport and visa if you are a person that needs one, a copy of your current or future rental agreement and a completed registration form (this sometimes can be downloaded in advance from the website of your Einwohnermeldeamt).

It is also possible to get it there and fill it out there. Sometimes you got some nice people working there that might help you fill it out with you quickly.

So in short:

- Passport
- Visa
- Filled out Meldebestätigung (Registration form)

If there are no problems, you will be given a confirmation form (Anmeldebestätigung) as proof of your registration.

Comment: (+1) Just to make sure: Does it mean that no proof of status (residence permit, visa or some such) is necessary for foreign citizens? (It would be useful to state it in the answer, either way).

Comment: Depends on the nationalitiy, i mean if you are EU citizen no need to have a residence permit or visa then, however if you need one then you have to bring it of course.

Comment: It's not completely obvious, in fact I vaguely recall that for some people (EU citizens' spouses?) it was the other way around: First *Anmeldung* then residence card. Am I wrong about that? And, under EU law, EU citizens might be required to prove they have a job and/or sufficient financial means and health insurance. Are those provisions enforced when seeking registration with a municipality? I really think it would be useful to find out and extend your answer to cover this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One more thing: what information do I have to provide in the registration form?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the documents for the Anmeldung in Berlin are available [on Berlin.de](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/120686/). You can find the original and an English translation [here](https://allaboutberlin.com/docs/anmeldung).

You will also need to bring the Einzugsbestätigung des Wohnungsgebers (or Wohnungsgeberbestätigung, or Vermieterbescheinigung), and valid ID document like your passport.

After your Anmeldung appointment, you will get a certificate of registration. A week or two later, you should receive your tax ID by mail.

You can see the full process (for Berlin) on [this page](https://allaboutberlin.com/guides/anmeldung-in-english-berlin).